# Выдает ошибку хотя все вроде написано правильно

Tags: python-3.x

это map

```
from  utils import randbool
from  utils import randcell
from  utils import randcell2
from  helicopter import Helicopter

CELL_TYPES = ""
#
class Map:
    
    def generate_river(self, l):
        rc = randcell(self.w, self.h)
        rx, ry = rc[0], rc[1]
        self.cells[rc[0]][rc[1]] = 2
        while 1 > 0:
            rc2 = randcell2 (rx, ry)
            rx2, ry2 = rc2[0], rc2[1]
            if (self.check_bounds(rx2, ry2)):
                self.cells[rx2][ry2] = 2
                rx, ry = rx2, ry2
                l -= 1   

    def generate_forest(self, r, mxr):
        for ri in range(self.h):
            for ci in range(self.w):
                if randbool(r, mxr):
                    self.cells[ri][ci] = 1

    def generate_tree(self):
        c = randcell(self.w, self.h)
        cx, cy = c[0], c[1]
        if(self.check_bounds(cx, cy) and self.cells[cx][cy == 0]):
            self.cells[cx][cy] = 1

    def print_map(self, helico): #Для чего функция?
        print('⬜️' * (self.w + 2))
        for ri in range(self.h):
            print('⬜️', end="")
            for ci in range(self.w):
                cell = self.cells[ri][ci]
                if(helico.x == ri and helico.y == ci):
                    print('8_2', end='')
                if(cell >= 0 and cell < len(CELL_TYPES)):
                    print(CELL_TYPES[cell], end="")
            print( '⬜️')
        print('⬜️' * (self.w + 2))

    def add_fire(self):
        c = randcell(self.w, self.h)
        cx, cy = c[0],c [1]
        if self.cells[cx][cy] == 1:
            self.cells[cx][cy] = 5

    def update_fires(self):
        for ri in range (self.h):
            for ci in range(self.w):
                cell = self.cells[ri][ci]
                if cell == 5:
                    self.cells[ri][ci] = 0
        for i in range(10):
            self.add_fire

    def check_bounds(self, x, y):
        if(x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= self.h or y >= self.w):
            return False
        return True

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.cells = [[0 for i in range(w)] for j in range (h)]

tmp = Map(30, 10)
tmp.generate_forest(3, 10)
tmp.generate_river(11)
tmp.print_map()
```

это main

```
from map import Map
import time
import os
from helicopter import Helicopter as Helico

TICK_SLEEP = 1
TREE_UPDATE = 50
FIRE_UPDATE = 100
MAP_W, MAP_H = 30, 10

field = Map(MAP_W, MAP_H)
field.generate_forest(3, 10)
field.generate_river(11)
field.add_fire()
field.add_fire()
field.add_fire()
field.add_fire()

helico = Helico(MAP_W, MAP_H)

tick = 1
while True:
    os.system('cls')
    field.print_map(helico)
    print('Tick', tick)
    field.print_map()
    tick += 1
    tick.sleep(TICK_SLEEP)
    if (tick % TREE_UPDATE == 0):
        field.generate_tree()
    if (tick % FIRE_UPDATE == 0):
        field.update_fires
```

это utils

```
from random import randint as rand

def randbool(r, mxr):
    t = rand(0, mxr)
    return (t <= r)

def randcell(w,h):
    tw = rand(0, w - 1)
    th = rand(0, h - 1)
    return(th, tw)

def randcell2(x, y):
    moves = [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)]
    t = rand(0, 4)
    dx, dy = moves[t][0], moves[t][1]
    return (x + dx, y + dy)
```

это helicopter

```
from utils import randcell


class Helicopter:
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        rc = randcell(w, h)
        rx, ry = rc[0], rc[1]
        self.x = rc
        self.y = ry
```

Это все коды которые нужны они каждые в своей рабочей области но ошибки выдает не пойму почему вроде все правильно
вот я запускаю map и выдает мне Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   tmp.generate_river(11)
 File "c:\Users\semon\launch.json\map.py", line 15, in generate_river
   rc2 = randcell2 (rx, ry)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "c:\Users\semon\launch.json\utils.py", line 15, in randcell2   
   dx, dy = moves[t][0], moves[t][1]
            ~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: и ещё дополнительные коды

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint as rand
...
def randcell2(x, y):
    moves = [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)]
    t = rand(0, 4)
    dx, dy = moves[t][0], moves[t][1]
             ~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Смотрим [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> `random.randint(a, b)`
> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

То есть `randint` вам выдаёт значения от `0` до `4` **включительно**. А у вас всего 4 элемента в списке - с индексами от `0` до `3`, индекс `4` вызовет ошибку, которую вы и видите.

Comment: а что делать щас вот таю ошибку выдает

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\semon\launch.json\map.py", line 76, in <module>
    tmp.generate_river(11)
  File "c:\Users\semon\launch.json\map.py", line 31, in generate_river
    self.cells[rx][ry] = 2
    ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^```